# WCF duplex binding broadcasting options

Tags: wcf, azure, windows-services, servicebus, duplex

I have a WCF service with duplex binding hosted within a windows service. The service has to continuously poll for changes in a datasource (Azure service bus to be specific, but type of datasource isn't really important). If there is any new change in the datasource, the service should immediately notify one or more clients.

I have gone through many different potential approaches of achieving this such as [Broadcasting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service), [Publish/Subscribe with WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22796/WCF-Implementation-of-the-Publisher-Subscriber-Mod), and [List based publish subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254(v=vs.110).aspx)

But in all these approaches, the chain of events is initiated explicitly by a client/publisher. For example in case of Pub-Sub, the whole chain of events is initiated when a publisher publishes something.

But in my scenario, there is no publisher. Service must itself poll onto a datasource and look for any new changes.

How do I achieve this in my scenario? Where should I have the polling logic?

One option is to have the polling logic in hosting environment (windows service) and call the publish of service whenever there is new data.

I am not sure how we can have the polling logic within the WCF service itself! Any leads/thoughts regarding this would be very helpful.